# Uncertainty about number format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

In Oracle Database, fields like this:

```
      example number(6,4) not null;
```

Indicate that I'm reserving 6 digits for this column, 4 that are being used from the point to the right and 2 for the point to the left.

Is this the same in MySQL?

Thanks!!! I know this is basic but I have some time working on databases and always this question...

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to check the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html) for quick answers like this.

> In a DECIMAL column declaration, the precision and scale can be (and usually is) specified; for example:
>
> salary DECIMAL(5,2)
>
> In this example, 5 is the precision and 2 is the scale. The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point.

The [decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) type has these constraints on scale and precision:

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments are as follows:
>
> - M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.
> - D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.